# Selenium WebDriverWait with expected conditions returns only the first found element (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following html elements:

1)

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-qa- 
id="main- 
go-button">Go</button>
      </span>
```

2)

```
<span class="input-group-btn" style="float: left;"><button type="button" 
wkda-autocomplete-update="update" class=" btn btn-default" data-qa- 
id="">Change</button></span>
```

3)

```
<span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" wkda-autocomplete- 
update="update" class=" btn btn-default" data-qa-id="">Change</button></span>
```

The regular element finder:

```
browser.find_elements_by_class_name("input-group-btn")
```

returns a list of three items, since there are three html parts that contain the same structure:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement 
(session="1fc51e63b34c7acfa37e3930c86fc46c", element="6bab5131-a508-41da- 
a7b7-1ccaae8dabda")>,
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement 
(session="1fc51e63b34c7acfa37e3930c86fc46c", element="26dfeaa3-d54c-4652- 
a84e-aae47d0574ba")>,
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement 
(session="1fc51e63b34c7acfa37e3930c86fc46c", element="7bb98d81-a576-41fd- 
be70-2aa2564f76b9")>]
```

I would like to select and click only the third element of this list, so I do:

```
browser.find_elements_by_class_name("input-group-btn")[2].text
```

and it works fine.

I would like though to find this element via the WebDriverWait. But when I run this:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "input-group-btn")))
```

it finds only the first element of the previous list, so it returns the first element found, but I would like to get the third one.

Do you know if there is any way to grab the third element instead of the first one found?

Comment: Can you post more code? maybe you are missing something or doing some badly (for example get elements, click or so something that change the website and try to continue iterate elemets without re-catch them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on last change button.Induce WebdriverWait and following XPATH.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"(//span[@class='input-group-btn']/button[text()='Change'])[last()]"))).click()
```

Comment: @mars : updated the answer try now and let me know how it goes?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a more specific selector to find your element. Since there are 3 elements found with `browser.find_elements_by_class_name("input-group-btn")`, you should write a more specific XPath selector. You don't need to wait for all 3 -- just for your specific button.

Based on the sample you provided, you could use the XPath `//button[text()='Change']`:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPath, "//button[text()='Change']")))
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Change']").text
```

Depending on what the HTML for 3rd button looks like, you can modify this XPath to suit your needs.

Comment: I posted all of them so you can see the differences. Apparently simply text()='Change' can not work since there is another one.